# XPath select element's img's src attribute

Tags: xpath

How to select "hello" from src attribute?

```
<div class="myClass">
  <img src="hello" />
</div>
```

I can select myClass > img with following code

```
//*[contains(@class, 'myClass')]/img
```

But how to get it's src tag? I've tried with errors:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'myClass')]/img attribute::src
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `@src`:

```
//div[@class="myClass"]/img/@src
```

Or, in case of multiple classes on `div` element, use `contains()`:

```
//div[contains(@class, "myClass")]/img/@src
```

Comment: I thought that `@src` will select all imgs with src attribute, not attribute itself.

Comment: @Ultra `/@src` would get the attribute value. "all imgs with src attribute" would select the following one: `//img[@src]`.

Answer (score -1):

//div[@class='myClass']/img

//div[@class='myClass']//img[@src='hello']

Comment: This select the img element but not the src attribute. The correct one is //div[@class="myClass"]//img/@src